# Render Grafana panel in PHP without IFRAME?

Tags: graph, iot, grafana

I tried to embed graph panel of Grafana using PHP's file_get_contents(). But, it doesn't print the graph. How to render Grafana graph in PHP without IFRAME?

Answer (score 0):

I mean you may generate own dashboard use ready libraries:
e.g. [grafana-dash-gen](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grafana-dash-gen)

or use API (REST) and in javascript generate own dashboard.